# "Данные по безопасности/эффективности" или "данные о(б) безопасности/эффективности"?

Tags: выбор-слов, предлоги

В инструкциях к лекарственным препаратам и других текстах о них встречаются выражения "данные по безопасности" и "данные о безопасности", "данные по эффективности" и "данные об эффективности". Первая пара фраз означает сведения о безопасности описываемого препарата (обычно это сведения о побочных эффектах). Вторая пара может означать, например, сведения о величине и стойкости лечебного эффекта препарата (например, если речь идет о лечении гипертонии, может быть указано, насколько сильно и на какое время препарат снижает артериальное давление).

Какой предлог лучше использовать: "по" или "об"? Есть ли между ними различие?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ответы Грамоты.ру на похожие темы**

**Вопрос № 277324.** Скажите, пожалуйста, какой вариант правильный: данные по остаточной стоимости или данные об остаточной стоимости?

Ответ справочной службы русского языка. Лучше: сведения об остаточной стоимости.

**Вопрос № 221785.** Как правильно: «данные по безопасности», «данные по эффективности» или «данные о безопасности», «данные о эффективности»?

Ответ справочной службы русского языка. Корректно: данные о безопасности, данные об эффективности.

**Разница между предлогами ПО и ОБ есть.** Предлог ПО указывает направление (различные данные, собранные по теме), а предлог О более конкретен (сведения о каком-либо вопросе в данной теме).

**Примеры:**

То и дело появляются тревожные **данные о** финансовом положении компании.

Рассмотрим более подробно **данные по** качеству воды в реке Москва, полученные летом 2003 г.

Подавляющее большинство исследований с ХЖГВ на различных возрастных группах, в которых были получены хорошие данные **о безопасности, иммуногенности и эффективности этой вакцины**, проводили при использовании двукратной вакцинации. [Преимущества и недостатки инактивированной и живой вакцины против гриппа // «Вопросы вирусологии», 2004.07.05]